# Webpack react chunk versioning

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How I can versioning my chunkFiles with a .../app_chunk1.js`?v=1` or something.

config.output have no version attribute or something.

it should be a url `query version parameter` else I will have 404 problems that the file not exist when change the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok got a solution if someones else is searching for a solution when you configurate it this way:

```
chunkFilename: 'app.chunk[id].js?v=[hash]',
```

the file `app.chunk1.js` will created and `app.chunk1.js?v=...` is requested.